# Android 2.0: how to add contact groups in the emulator?

Tags: android, emulation, contacts

how to add contact groups in the  emulator or sync with Google contacts or device contacts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't.

You have to get a free application that does this and push to the emulator. You can use the Contacts->Import from VCF function to import contacts from a vcard file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a local contact on you android emulator
2. Run this code/app to your emulator:

   // ------------------------------------------------------ Create Google
   // Group ()

   ```
   public void createGoogleGroup(String groupName) {
   ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();ops = new Arraenter code hereyList<ContentProviderOperation>();

   ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
           .newInsert(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
           .withValue(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE, groupName)
           .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                   "com.google")
           .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                   googleAccountName).build());
   try {

       context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
               ops);

   } catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e("Error Creating Group", e.toString());
   }}
   ```

   Hope it helpes